What is wrong with my Merge String Alternately function from leetcode 1768
enter image description here
class Solution {
    public:
        string mergeAlternately(string word1, string word2) {
        int len1 = word1.length();
        int len2 = word2.length();
        string ans;
        for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < word1.length() + word2.length(); i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0 && j < len1 || k == len2) {
                ans += word1[j];
                j++;
            }
            if (i % 2 == 1 && k < len2 || j == len1) {
                ans += word2[k];
                k++;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
};

I checked if I am appending null character but it is less than Len so I have no idea what is wrong with the code.

Did you really check if you were appending a 0? https://godbolt.org/z/fxcP7TcrG Pay attention to the warnings.

Starting with an image and code makes your question look bad. I advise reading [ask].

"but it is less than Len" -- To what does "it" refer here? Grammatically, the antecedent is "null character" but I doubt that is what you meant. Related, what is "Len"? Your code has len1 and len2, but no Len. Writing more carefully and explaining why this claim is true might lead you to discover your error.

You need else if there. Then your code will pass.

This is not a [mcve]

The logic of your program requires that only one character be appended to variable ans in each iteration of the loop. That's because variable i is incremented only once per iteration.
This causes problems when len1 <= len2. After the final character of word1 is appended to ans, variable j is incremented, which makes it equal to len1. When the following if-statement is executed, it finds that j == len1, so it appends a second character to ans (from word2). That means two characters have been added to ans on the same iteration, but i is incremented only once.
This creates an off-by-one error that causes the loop to be executed one time too many. During the final iteration, you enter the land of undefined behavior, when word1 is indexed using a subscript that is out of bounds. This happens, because k == len2.
if (i % 2 == 0 && j < len1 || k == len2) {
    ans += word1[j];  // UB - subscript j == len1
    j++;              // now j == len1 + 1
}

With UB, all bets are off, but it may be that the small string optimization has filled the string buffer with null characters ('\0'), so that is the character selected when word1[len1] is accessed.
Afterwards, j is set to len1 + 1. The if-statement for word2, therefore, does not attempt to add another character.
if (i % 2 == 1 && k < len2 || j == len1) {
    ans += word2[k];
    k++;
}

This analysis considered only those cases where len1 <= len2. However, an analogous problem exists where len1 > len2, when word2 runs out of characters before word1.
A simple fix
@Unmitigated supplied a simple fix in the comments: use else-if when testing for word2. With that change, only one character will be appended to ans on each iteration.
if (i % 2 == 0 && j < len1 || k == len2) {
    ans += word1[j];
    j++;
}
else if (i % 2 == 1 && k < len2 || j == len1) {
    ans += word2[k];
    k++;
}

A complete program
The following program includes a driver that runs all three examples from the LeetCode website.
// main.cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

// This using declaration allows the LeetCode Solution 
// to be used without modifying its function signature.
using std::string;

class Solution {
public:
    string mergeAlternately(string word1, string word2) {
        int len1 = word1.length();
        int len2 = word2.length();
        string ans;
        for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < word1.length() + word2.length(); i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0 && j < len1 || k == len2) {
                ans += word1[j];
                j++;
            }
            else if (i % 2 == 1 && k < len2 || j == len1) {
                ans += word2[k];
                k++;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}; 
void solve(
    std::string_view heading,
    std::string const& word1,
    std::string const& word2)
{
    std::string ans{ Solution{}.mergeAlternately(word1, word2) };
    std::cout
        << heading
        << "\n"
        << "\n  Input: word1 = " << std::quoted(word1) 
        <<          ", word2 = " << std::quoted(word2)
        << "\n  Output: " << std::quoted(ans) << ", length = " << ans.length()
        << "\n\n";
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << "LeetCode 1768. Merge Strings Alternately"
        "\nhttps://leetcode.com/problems/merge-strings-alternately/description/"
        "\n\n";
    solve("Example 1", "abc", "pqr");
    solve("Example 2", "ab", "pqrs");
    solve("Example 3", "abcd", "pq");
}
// end file: main.cpp

Output
LeetCode 1768. Merge Strings Alternately
https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-strings-alternately/description/

Example 1

  Input: word1 = "abc", word2 = "pqr"
  Output: "apbqcr", length = 6

Example 2

  Input: word1 = "ab", word2 = "pqrs"
  Output: "apbqrs", length = 6

Example 3

  Input: word1 = "abcd", word2 = "pq"
  Output: "apbqcd", length = 6

A simpler approach
The solution below adds two characters to the answer on each iteration of the loop. It stops when either word1 or word2 is exhausted.
Upon exit from the loop, i and j are tested to determine whether any characters remain, respectively, in word1 or word2. Whatever remains is appended to the answer in a single "chunk," using a substring.
Because it uses type std::string::size_type throughout, and does not mix it with int, it compiles without any warnings.
class Solution
{
public:
    string mergeAlternately(string word1, string word2) {
        auto const len1 = word1.length();  // Here, auto == std::string::size_type
        auto const len2 = word2.length();
        std::string ans;
        ans.reserve(len1 + len2);  // avoid reallocations as `ans` grows.

        // use correct type
        std::string::size_type i{};  // index into `word1`
        std::string::size_type j{};  // index into `word2`

        // while "both strings have characters remaining"
        while (i < len1 && j < len2) {
            ans.push_back(word1[i++]);
            ans.push_back(word2[j++]);
        }

        // append whatever remains
        if (i < len1)
            ans += word1.substr(i);
        else if (j < len2)
            ans += word2.substr(j);
        return ans;
    }
};

